# llncs: Separated authors

Tags: titles, lncs

How I can make authors separately in `llncs` environment like in the example below? [image]

I made it in one line using following command, but I don't know how to make them separately:

```
\author{
 ABC\inst{1} 
 \and XYZ\inst{1},
}

\institute{
Institute ABC\\ 
\email{ mail@mail }\thanks{Additional note}
}
```

Comment: The `llncs` class is for submission to Springer and *they* decide how the author names will appear.

Comment: @egreg What does it mean? That I can not create authors names separately?

Comment: Sure you can, but your paper will either be rejected or they just put it back to their standards. The important question is: Are you submitting to Springer?

Comment: @Johannes_B No, not to Springer

Comment: But this is the template file for Springer journals. Does the journal you are submitting to have a LaTeX template? Use this instead. If not, my next step would be to ask the publisher for some details on submitting content. If its ok to use Springers template, we can find a solution (we can find one even if its not ok).

Comment: Some journals want to have a word file, i am a little worried that you are spending time on making a nice LaTeX document just to find out later that you need to submit something else. So please don't take my former comment the wrong way.

Comment: @Johannes_B Please make your comments into an answer

Answer (score 1):

Many Journals have templates out there that submitting authors
can enter their title and personal information in a standardized
way. That makes the work of the journal editors more easy.
The overall look of titles of all articles in one journal looks
similar, which is an important feature.

If you do not want to submit to a journal, don't use the template
they provide. The most practical approach is to use standard
article class and define something like a title by hand.

[image: zivaSpringerTemplateTitle]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\email{\urlstyle{sf}}
\begin{document}
\begingroup%titlestuff
{\Large\centering \bfseries
    Salsa dancing Sloths \par%
}\vspace{.8cm}
\begin{center}
    \sffamily
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        Saar Cohen\\
        School of Computer Science\\
        \email{saarco@somehost.org}
    \end{minipage}\hspace{.1\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        Yossi Matias\\
        School of Computer Science\\
        \email{matias@somehost.org}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\endgroup%endtitlestuff

\section{rock around the duck}
\blindtext
\end{document}

This is not the most robust approach though. Some more
information on how to change the appearence of a title, or more
prcisely titlepage, can be found in [How to customize a title
page]().
```